# Blazor MAUI <select> element - events not occurring

Tags: .net, select, blazor, maui

I see in another question, select control in maui blazor not work properly :  (you need use size=2 or the list not show). It's a reported bug with no solution.

But even using size 2, i have found another problem, events not working, i can not  see any errors but if i try with @bind or @onchange or  @onclick,  no events works.
The same @bind or @onchange in  input control works nicely.

```
</label><input id="chkCargoIncluido" type="checkbox" @bind="DoStuff" name="chkCargoIncluido"></span>;
```

works,

```
<select name="cboPaisDestino"  size="4" id="cboPaisDestino" @onchange="DoStuff  ">
```

Does nothing.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You could post it too https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: thanks, do it . https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5188